# How do you get a "bigger" font with react-native?

Tags: react-native

In CSS I can do percentages with fonts, so I can ask for font that is 120% of the base font, but in react-native, all I have are unitless numbers.  I'd like to be able to get a slightly larger font, like 120%, but the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html) only seem to cover picking a number.  It also fails to mention the default size (if I don't specify a fontSize parameter).

Is there some sane way to say current font size times 1.2?

Answer (score 0):

I don't no why React-Native have not documented the default font size. But you can easily find it through manual testing, my version of React-Native (0.43.0-rc.4) uses **14** as default font size(probably yours also should use this).

Also to use 1.2 times the base font size, just write a util function

```
    getFontSize(scale) {
     DEFAULT_SIZE = 14;
     return Math.round(scale * DEFAULT_SIZE);
    }
```

now set your

```
fontSize: getFontSize(1.2),
```

Another way to do this will be to manually set label names to a set of numbers like

```
FONT_SMALL = 12
FONT_NORMAL = 14
FONT_BIG = 16
```

use it everywhere in your fontSize property instead of using 1.2 times the normal text like

```
fontSize: FONT_BIG,
```